# Logging Filtered parameter in Byebug

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, byebug

I would like to know what would happen if I print out the value of a *filtered* parameters in `byebug`. Would it be `[FILTER]` or `the actual value` or an `empty string`.

e.g. password and credit card fields

I am getting empty string, so I'm not sure whether that value exist or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in console:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "email"=>"test@ff.ff", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "commit"=>"Sing in"}
```

use `byebug`:

```
(byebug) params
{"utf8"=>"✓", "email"=>"test@ff.ff", "password"=>"11111111", "commit"=>"Sing in", "action"=>"create", "controller"=>"sessions"}
```